# Magento WSDL file the same for each store

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, soap-api-v2, wsdl

Is the WSDL file generated from each store the same with regards to structure and available components or is it different for each store (can each store define its own datatypes etc.) I am wondering this, as the SOAP v2 API for Magento 1 has the same methods/operations regardless of customisations?

Answer (score 1):

The WSDL is the same, you can pass store_id as parameters.

Comment: Please consider adding more detail info. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/54021)

Comment: What do you mean? The question was is the wsdl the same for each store. I answered his question with yes it is.

Comment: That was system generated comment. :(

Comment: Automation fail